# PHP preg_match words inside string and manage each matching result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need to manage each matching result, depending on each result (word).

Strings are SQL sentences and I need to check all words (table names) in the string (SQL sentence) starting with the `site_` prefix (words starting with `site_`).

Depending on the word (table name like `site_customers`, `site_products`, etc), I will change the word with another different.

Example:

My string (SQL sentence):

```
SELECT * FROM site_customers LEFT JOIN site_products ....
```

First.- Extract `site_*` words (site_customer and site_products in this case).
Words are not always delimited by spaces, also by `\n` and `\t` chars.

Second.- for these matching results, change them in the appropriate way: I need to replace `site_customers` with `site_customers_02`, and `site_products` with `new_site_products`, and I cannot use other replacement system because there are a lot of tables and a lot of conditions to evaluate.

In this case, result should be:

```
SELECT * FROM site_customers_02 LEFT JOIN new_site_products ....<br/><br/>
```

Comment: Right now, based on what you've given, it sounds like simple search&replace. You say you can't use other replace system than regexp. But why? Should the same word be replaced by different things in some cases? Can you give any more info?

Comment: 400 tables. INSERT, SELECT and UPDATE sentences. DEpending on the month, the replacement is different, and also the table names are different. The only thing to look for table names is the PREFIX "site_". Extracting the tables, I will know waht to do with each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example you have given, you can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with arrays of patterns and replacements. Note we use `\b` (word boundary) to ensure that we only match (for example) `site_products` and not something like `aasite_products` or `site_productsxx`.

```
$string = 'SELECT * FROM site_customers LEFT JOIN site_products';
$patterns = array(
    '/\b(site_customers)\b/',
    '/\b(site_products)\b/'
    );
$replacements = array(
    '${1}_02',
    'new_$1'
    );
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM site_customers_02 LEFT JOIN new_site_products
```

You should be able to adapt this code to your needs if they are slightly different from the question you have asked.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/IZWkL)

Answer (score 0):

You can match your table names with `/\bsite_[a-zA-Z]*/`. If they contain numbers, you should also match them with `/\bsite_[a-zA-Z0-9]*/`.

---

Then you can replace it with new string:

```
<?php

$string = 'SELECT * FROM site_customers LEFT JOIN site_products';

$pattern = '/\bsite_[a-zA-Z0-9]*/';

$replacement = '$0_02';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

This will threat `site_customers` and `site_products` same. To both it will append `_02`.

Example on 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/Ti7n4

---

You can also threat first and second table separately, but you need to know the whole query:

```
<?php

$string = 'SELECT * FROM site_customers LEFT JOIN site_products';

$pattern = '/SELECT \* FROM (\bsite_[a-zA-Z0-9]*) LEFT JOIN (\bsite_[a-zA-Z0-9]*)/';

$replacement = 'SELECT * FROM $1_02 LEFT JOIN new_$2';

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Example on 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/0YorR

---

You can also extract words like `site_` and later replace them:

```
<?php

$re = '/\bsite_[a-zA-Z0-9]*/';
$query = 'SELECT * FROM site_customers LEFT JOIN site_products';

preg_match_all($re, $query, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);

// Replace old tables with new ones
$old = [
    $matches[0][0], // First table name
    $matches[1][0], // Second table name
];

$new = [
    $matches[0][0] . '_02', // Append _02
    'new_' . $matches[1][0], // Prepand new_
];

$query = str_replace($old, $new, $query);

// Print the new query
echo $query;
```

Example on 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/BMpPR

Comment: And only extracting the words "site_" into an array with a callback function to evaluate the replacement?

Comment: @Tango I added this in my third example. I also changed few thing in other examples.